# In newer Getopt::Long How do I set default optional values

Tags: perl, getopt-long

In Perl's Getopt::Long version 2.39 I could use

```
use Getopt::Long qw( :config gnu_getopt );
GetOptions(
   \my %opts, 
   "codon-view|c:20",    # Optional value, default 20
   "consensus|C:50", 
   ...
)
```

to indicate that if I use `-c` the default value would be 20 put in `%opts`under key `codon-view` when `-c` is given but no explicit value for it is there. On the other hand `-c` or `--codon-view` is not supplied, then no value in the hash table is stored for in `%opts`.

In 2.48 this no longer works and I don't see in [Getopt::Long's documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)

```
$ perl -E'
   use Getopt::Long qw( :config gnu_getopt );
   say $Getopt::Long::VERSION;
   GetOptions(\my %opts, "codon-view|c:20");
   say $opts{"codon-view"} // "[undef]"
' -- -c
2.39
20

$ perl -E'
   use Getopt::Long qw( :config gnu_getopt );
   say $Getopt::Long::VERSION;
   GetOptions(\my %opts, "codon-view|c:20");
   say $opts{"codon-view"} // "[undef]"
' -- -c
2.48
[undef]
```

How can I achieve the old behavior?

Help!

Comment: Are you sure that worked in 2.39? Going all the way back to 2.24 (released in 2000), the [documentation for options with values](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/JV/Getopt-Long-2.24/lib/Getopt/Long.pm#Options-with-values) consistently shows option specs of the form `tag=s` or `tag:i`, not `tag:20`.

Comment: I've modified the post to include this. What you get matches my behavior. It is only when `-c` or `--codon-view` is given without a value that the behavior changes betwee 2.39 and 2.48. Also there are changes in FindOption that change between those two versions with respect to `gnu_getopt`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, Search for `: number`

Comment: This is a change introduced in 2.48. I'm not sure, but I think it was done unintentionally, so I filed a [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=114999).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a change introduced in 2.48.

```
$ perl -E'
   use Getopt::Long qw( :config gnu_getopt );
   say $Getopt::Long::VERSION;
   GetOptions(\my %opts, "codon-view|c:20");
   say $opts{"codon-view"} // "[undef]"
' -- -c
2.47
20

$ perl -E'
   use Getopt::Long qw( :config gnu_getopt );
   say $Getopt::Long::VERSION;
   GetOptions(\my %opts, "codon-view|c:20");
   say $opts{"codon-view"} // "[undef]"
' -- -c
2.48
[undef]
```

I'm not sure, but I think it was done unintentionally, so I filed a [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=114999).

---

```
use Getopt::Long qw( :config gnu_getopt );
```

is short for

```
use Getopt::Long qw( :config gnu_compat bundling permute no_getopt_compat );
```

How invested are you in using `gnu_compat`?

```
$ perl -E'
   use Getopt::Long qw( :config gnu_getopt );
   say $Getopt::Long::VERSION;
   GetOptions(\my %opts, "codon-view|c:20");
   say $opts{"codon-view"} // "[undef]"
' -- -c
2.48
[undef]

$ perl -E'
   use Getopt::Long qw( :config gnu_compat bundling permute no_getopt_compat );
   say $Getopt::Long::VERSION;
   GetOptions(\my %opts, "codon-view|c:20");
   say $opts{"codon-view"} // "[undef]"
' -- -c
2.48
[undef]

$ perl -E'
   use Getopt::Long qw( :config bundling permute no_getopt_compat );
   say $Getopt::Long::VERSION;
   GetOptions(\my %opts, "codon-view|c:20");
   say $opts{"codon-view"} // "[undef]"
' -- -c
2.48
20
```

> `gnu_compat` controls whether `--opt=` is allowed, and what it should do. Without `gnu_compat`, `--opt=` gives an error. With `gnu_compat`, `--opt=` will give option `opt` and empty value. This is the way GNU getopt_long() does it.

So if you're ok with `--codon-view=` assigning zero to `$opts{"codon-view"}`, simply use

```
use Getopt::Long qw( :config bundling permute no_getopt_compat );
```

instead of

```
use Getopt::Long qw( :config gnu_getopt );
```

Comment: Since this is a usability thing, I'll need to ask users to experiment. What I've done for now is use the 2.39 code copied into the module. Given what you say, I suppose I can increase the version up to 2.47 or so.

Comment: Look again. My solution won't affect any of your users. It simply makes `--opt=` stop throwing an error.

Comment: It looks like the documentation for `gnu_compat` is wrong. `perl -MGetopt::Long=:config,gnu_compat -E'GetOptions(\%opts, "foo:1") or die; say "<$opts{foo}>"' -- --foo=` prints `<0>`; removing `gnu_compat` prints `<1>` (instead of giving an error).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, It does die without `gnu_compat` for `=` options. /// Getopt::Long's test suite is woefully lacking.

Comment: @ikegami just checked. Yep this works as you say. And this should be fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Set the default value before the `GetOptions()` call. If the option is not provided on the command line, then the default value will not be overwritten.

```
$ perl -MGetopt::Long -E '$c=20;GetOptions("c=i"=>\$c); say $c' -- -c 14
14

$ perl -MGetopt::Long -E '$c=20;GetOptions("c=i"=>\$c); say $c' --
20
```

There is [a trivial example](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Options-with-values) in the `Getopt::Long` documentation.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear about the previous behavior. If `-c` is not given then then that key isn't in a hash. If it is set, then and only then does the value for that key have a default value. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I like to assign my opts to a hash..

```
GetOptions(\ my %opt,
    'codon-view|c:i',
);

if ( exists $opt{'codon-view'} ) {
    print "User triggered '-c' flag\n";
    $opt{'codon-view'} ||= 20;
    printf( "codon-view: %d\n", $opt{'codon-view'} );
}
```

Now if a user runs `./you-app -c` with no argument, the `$opt{c}` key gets created, but it's value is `undef`, so you much check if it was triggered with `exists`.

The `||=` operator assigns the right-hand side to the left-hand side only if the left-hand side is `falsey` ( usually `undef` ). A caveat is that if someone does `-c 0` it will assign the default... but I'm going to go ahead and assume `0` is probably  a bad argument for your flag.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't report my situation fully. First, yes, I do use an options hash. Also, I use `use Getopt::Long qw(config gnu_getopt);` Your example does work when gnu_getopt is not specified in the use statement. However when it is specified, then your example no longer works. Also it is a little more cumbersome and puts in two places what `codon-view|c:20` does. If we can can address the problem when gnu_getopt is specified, I'll accept this if no better solution is found.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible but less good solution: include a copy of Getopt::Long.pm, It's only one file, but I have changed the package namespace to something different, e.g. MyPackage::GetoptLong.

This is not an ideal answer, but it is something to keep in mind if you need something to keep compatibility and don't have the better ikegami solution.